# server side data annotation not working properly for DateTime array type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, html-helper

I have an array type DateTime property in my model for DateRangePickerFor component. 
Model:

```
public class DateRange
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the value")]
    public DateTime?[] value { get; set; }
}
```

When the post action is performed the model value takes as below type. Since this control needs two array values by default and because of the nullable type the below value is what I get.

```
{System.DateTime?[2]}
[0]: null
[1]: null
```

Hence, in this case, the value is set as value[null, null] and the given annotation "Please enter the value" is not set.
So could anyone please suggest the way to handle the `DateTime` array type and make the Data annotation work for this case.
controller:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
      return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Index(DateRange model)
  {
      //posted value is obtained from the model
      DateRangeValue.value = model.value;
      return View(DateRangeValue);
  }
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    // Here i use my custom component (i.e) DateRangerPicker which takes the two date array values and displays like this "3/3/2020 - 9/3/2021"
    @Html.DateRangePickerFor(m => m.value)

    <input type="submit" value="Save Student Details" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modifying your custom component so it takes two separate properties instead of a two-dimension array of type `DateTime?`.  Your array itself is not null, just the values of its two elements, thus you are not getting your error message.

Comment: my requirement is to pass the array type DateTime? and I cannot able to modify my custom component. Actually my post is null only but with the type of system.DateTime[null,null]. Hence I need to handle this case only. If I change this type to null in the post actions means also, the annotation value is not set.